# PHP Insert multi-dimensional array values in csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have the following array. For simplicity, i have only posted one item but it's a big array that contains a huge number of keys and values

```
Array
(
[Maths] => Array
    (
        [00] => 0
        [01] => 0
        [02] => 0
        [03] => 0
        [04] => 0
        [05] => 0
        [06] => 0
        [07] => 0
        [08] => 0
        [09] => 0
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0
        [12] => 0
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => 0
        [17] => 9
        [18] => 5128
        [19] => 5763
        [20] => 1734
        [21] => 632
        [22] => 299
        [23] => 190
    )
```

I would like to put the contents of the array into a csv file which will be structured like this. One line per outer array and conctenate the values of the inner array to it.

So the above array will appear like this. Please bear in mind that it's not a static array. All the information in the array is dynamic

```
Math,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,5128,5763,1734,632,299,190
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data=Array(...);
$csv="";
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $csv.=$key.",".implode(",", $value)."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your structure is something like:

array ( key1 => array(), key2 => array() ... )
you could do this:

```
$csvOutput = "";

foreach ($baseAy as $key => $subAy) {

    $csvOutput.= "\n".$key.",";

    foreach ($subAy as $value) {
         $csvOutput.= $value.",";
    }
}

print_r($csvOutput);
```

Comment: above code gives comma(,) at the end, instead of inner foreach, you can use implode with comma(,) and concatenate.